# ipython-cypher in Python: cypher.run.Connection object parameter

Tags: python, neo4j, ipython, cypher

I'm trying to use ipython-cypher to run Neo4j Cypher queries (and return a Pandas dataframe) in a Python program. I have no trouble forming a connection and running a query when using IPython Notebook, but when I try to run the same query outside of IPython, as per the documentation:

http://ipython-cypher.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html#usage-out-of-ipython

```
import cypher

results = cypher.run("MATCH (n)--(m) RETURN n.username, count(m) as neighbors", 
          "http://XXX.XXX.X.XXX:xxxx")
```

I get the following error:
neo4jrestclient.exceptions.StatusException: Code [401]: Unauthorized. No permission -- see authorization schemes.
Authorization Required

and

Format: (http|https)://username:password@hostname:port/db/name, or one of dict_keys([])

Now, I was just guessing that that was how I should enter a Connection object as the last parameter, because I couldn't find any additional documentation explaining how to connect to a remote host using Python, and in IPython, I am able to do:

```
%load_ext cypher
results = %cypher http://XXX.XXX.X.XXX:xxxx MATCH (n)--(m) RETURN n.username, 
count(m) as neighbors
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation has a section for the [API](http://ipython-cypher.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cypher.html#cypher.run.run). When used outside of IPython and in need to connect to a different host, just using the parameter `conn` and passing a string should work.

```
import cypher

results = cypher.run("MATCH (n)--(m) RETURN n.username, count(m) as   neighbors",
                     conn="http://XXX.XXX.X.XXX:xxxx")
```

But also consider that with the new authentication support in Neo4j 2.2, you need to set the new password before connecting from `ipython-cypher`. I will fix this as soon as I implement the forcing password change mechanism in `neo4jrestclient`, the library underneath.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the API and the conn parameter. When I add it, I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'session', but I assume this has to do with my not having set a new password. I'm not sure how to do that, but I'll poke around. Thank you again for your response.

Comment: Now that was an error on my side. It should be fixed now in the new 0.2.2. And as for the auth, try browsing to `http://XXX.XXX.X.XXX:xxxx`, change the password for the user `neo4j`, and then add that to the host URI in the `ipython-cypher`'s `conn` parameter: `http://neo4j:password@XXX.XXX.X.XXX:xxxx`